# Normalize strings in a dataframe or json list - python

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, unicode

EDIT: I need to access the ds data and normalize the text. I tried changing json to df to try some functions I found but no success. In the end it doesn't matter if I have a dataframe, json... The main issue is to able to normalize the text.

From the following =

```
data = [
        {
            "id": 504,
            "ds": "A description with ressonância magnética"
        },
        {   
            "id": 505,
            "ds": "Another description that contains word with accentuation"
        }]
```

I'm changing it to a pandas DataFrame
`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`
 `print(df['ds'])`

And I try to access df['ds'] to use `.apply(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df['ds'])` because I need to remove all words with any type of accentuation, eg. 'à', 'â', 'ã', etc.

But I get 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply''

Other thing I tried was

```
        def remove_accents(input_str):
            nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
            only_ascii = nfkd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
            return only_ascii
        
        df['ds'] = df['ds'].apply(remove_accents)
```

But I get the error 'TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be str, not bytes'

I'm new to python so forgive me lol
But I've tried many things.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Instead of describing the code you have, please share the code you're running, or an example of code that demonstrates the problem. It's not clear what you mean by "I'm changing it to a json df = pd.DataFrame(df)  print(df['ds']"

Answer (score 0):

To convert dataframe to json.
`df.to_json("data.json", orient="records")`

I have the following function :

```
def remove_accents(input_str):
    import unicodedata
    nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nkfd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii.decode('utf-8')
df['ds'] = df['ds'].apply(remove_accents)
```

With the following df :

```
data = [
        {
            "id": 504,
            "ds": "A description of the product"
        },
        {
            "id": 505,
            "ds": "Another description that contâins word with ãccentuation"
        }]
```

And my output is :

```
    id                                                        ds
0  504                              A description of the product
1  505  Another description that contains word with accentuation
```

Running the function without `.decode('utf-8')` will give you

```
    id                                                           ds
0  504                              b'A description of the product'
1  505  b'Another description that contains word with accentuation'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of non-ASCII characters, just encode to ascii, then decode again:

```py
>>> df['ds'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')

0                         A description of the product
1    Another description that contains word with ac...
Name: ds, dtype: object
```

Similarly you can pass `utf-8` if you want to keep the `utf` characters

Comment: Thank you! I've tried before but I get 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe2' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)'

Comment: @GNova see the updated answer, you need to pass `'ignore'` to the `errors` parameter of `str.encode`

Comment: I included an example!

Comment: @GNova  Accept the answer if it worked or let me know if you are still finding some issues with the provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### Define data with accentuation

use also german/ french accents

```
data = [
      {"id": 504,
       "ds": "A description of the product"
      },
      {"id": 505,
       "ds": "Another dèscription thàt contains word with accentuation"
      }]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df['ds'])
```

#### Pandas DataFrame .apply

```
df['ds'].apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x))
```

#### Pandas Series string methods

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html

---

At this point your accentuated characters are divided into the character and the relative accent(è à é, german, french...).

You can use by your own the *string.translate* amd *string.maketrans*